не обьявляется перменная, ошибку пишет
я пишу, хочу обьявить перменную:\

    private   ActivityMainBinding binding;
  //val   URL: String
    URL = "https://spektr-ekb.ru";

и мне пишет ошибку:
Expecting member declaration
и так и так пробовал обьявлять перемнную

Причем, если я так обьявляю
  var  URL = "https://spektr-ekb.ru";

то приложение запускается, но пишет другую ошибку
Property 'URL' could be private


Этот вопрос похож на: Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде на C#?. Если вы считаете его другим, пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос, чётко обозначив отличие и/или почему ответы на вопрос не помогли в вашем случае.

@eccs0103, в данном случае код на Котлине )

@NowhereMan мда. Все языки у меня кроме JS и C# отключены. И раз этот появился я думал "Ну точно не JS, скорее всего C#". А тут оказывается вообще язык не отметили

"Property 'URL' could be private" - это вообще не ошибка, это предупреждение, что можно сделать это свойство приватным. var URL = "https://spektr-ekb.ru"; - в целом правильно. С указанием типа будет так: var URL: String = "https://spektr-ekb.ru";. Плюс, если это константа, которая никогда не будет меняться кодом, есть заменить var на val.

Вот решение вопроса: помогло:


        navView.setOnItemSelectedListener { item ->
            when (item.itemId) {
                R.id.navigation_home -> {
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "aaaa on  ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    true
                }

                else -> {
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "fffff on  ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    true
                }
            }

        }




пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
